# is it possible to project ovals on Android MapView?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, gis, map-projections

Working on a project that requires marking oval areas on a map. is this possible? has anyone done this before? Searching around I found lots of refrences of how to draw projected circles , but not ovals. would appreciate any insight or help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is! 
I created an ItemizedOverlay which draws the ovals i need using the project method to translate my geopoints to screen coords.

My issue now, and i hope someone has some insight, Is it possible to create an ItemizedOverlay (or some other kind of overlay) that DOES NOT draw an icon.
In my case i want to draw the ovals on the map but i dont want a default icon to be drawn.
currently the ovals are being drawn and the default icon is being placed at their center, the default icon provided to the itemizedOverlay constructor.

I have tried constructing with NULL as default icon but it provokes a NULLpointerException.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the second issue metioned above, I created an empty Drawable (extended Drawable and left everything empty), and instance of this class is sent as the default marker, thus making the default marker actually empty.

Works as expected.